# Prove comparison principle for $u_t + f(u)_x = k u_{xx} + g(t,x)$ with $g \in L^\infty(0,T; L^2(\mathbb R))$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, parabolic-pde

Let us consider the PDE
$$u_t + f(u)_x = k u_{xx} + g(t,x),$$ with $k>0$, $g \in L^\infty(0,T; L^2(\mathbb R))$ and $f\in C^2(\mathbb R$) and $f$ strictly convex.

Assume $u(0,\cdot) = u_0(\cdot) \in L^\infty(\mathbb R) \cap L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Assume that there exists a smooth solution $u$ of this PDE. How can I prove that  $$u(t,\cdot) \in L^\infty(\mathbb R), \quad t >0 \ ?$$
Or, for a fixed $T>0$, that $$\Vert u \Vert_{L^\infty((0,T)\times\mathbb R)} <\infty$$
holds?

Comment: You probably need some assumption on $u(0, \cdot)$. Also, what type of solution are you asking about?

Comment: @Wraith1995 I've edited the question